# Git repo Access not working with access keys

Tags: linux, git, ssh, version-control, bitbucket

1. I've generated ssh keys for user "devuser" using ssh-keygen command
2. after the private and public keys are generated, I've added the public key to the project's Access Keys list in bitbucket
3. when i try cloning the repo from bitbucket i get the below error

```
git clone ssh://git@host.fqdn.net:6999/dev-project/test-repo.git
Cloning into 'test-repo'...
ssh: Could not resolve hostname /home/devuser/.ssh2/id_rsa_2048_b: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

When i try the same the same steps for a different user on the same host, works fine for me. Appreciate any pointers

Comment: Do you have anything in your `~/.ssh/config` file (particularly entries relevant to `host.fqdn.net`)?

Comment: what's the ssh -vT git@host.fqdn.net:6999 output?

Comment: OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 66: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to host.fqdn.net [53.124.43.134] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 53.124.43.134 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host host.fqdn.net port 22: Connection refused

Answer (score 0):

To add to [larsks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147356/larsks)' [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68552874/git-repo-access-not-working-with-access-keys#comment121153129_68552874), try:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -F /dev/null' git clone ssh://git@host.fqdn.net:6999/dev-project/test-repo.git
```

Or

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -F /dev/null -i /home/devuser/.ssh2/id_rsa_2048_b' \
git clone ssh://git@host.fqdn.net:6999/dev-project/test-repo.git
```

That will force SSH to [ignore your `~/.ssh/config`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110284/7490).

- If this works, then have a look at said `config` file.
- If not, then, as noted, have a look at `ssh -vT git@host.fqdn.net:6999` to understand what local files are considered by SSH during its interaction with the remote site.

Comment: OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips 26 Jan 2017 debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 66: Applying options for * debug1: Connecting to host.fqdn.net [53.124.43.134] port 22. debug1: connect to address 53.124.43.134 port 22: Connection refused ssh: connect to host host.fqdn.net port 22: Connection refused

Comment: I get the same output for the other user which works

Comment: @user3539927 I just edited the answer: can you add the private key to `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`, for testing?